# Can I use org-latex-export-to-pdf to convert headlines to nested bullets?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I've been using headline levels in org-mode as essentially bullets. When I convert to PDF, I get a numbered list. Is there a way I can export those as nested bullets instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:0 num:nil toc:nil
* foo
** bar
*** baz
* fu
```

but consider changing your habits: headlines are for sections with perhaps somewhat extensive text under the headline. If you want bullets, consider using a list (do `C-h i g (org) plain lists` for more information):

```
- foo
  - bar
     - baz
- fu
```