# Org Mode export bullets instead of numbers

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs

When exporting an Org-mode buffer to Text or ODT, I'm getting the following:

```
 1. Lorem
 1.1. Ipsum
 1.1.1. Dolor
 1.1.2. Sit
```

I'd like to change it to a bulleted list rather than numbered (closer to Org Mode view itself):

```
* Lorem
  + Ipsum
    - Dolor
    - Sit
```

[image: original-org-mode-view]

(the specific bullets chosen are just an example).

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use org-latex-export-to-pdf to convert headlines to nested bullets?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64400/can-i-use-org-latex-export-to-pdf-to-convert-headlines-to-nested-bullets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the text/ascii exporter, I would say:

1. Add `#+OPTIONS: num:0 H:0` in your org document
2. Customize the variable `org-ascii-bullets` to choose the character used for each level, for instance:

   ```lisp
   (setq org-ascii-bullets '((ascii ?* ?+ ?-) (latin1 ?* ?+ ?-) (utf-8 ?* ?+ ?-)))
   ```

The following org document:

```
#+OPTIONS: num:0 H:0 author:nil toc:nil

* Toto
** Tata
*** Titi
```

will be exported in text/utf-8 as:

```
* Toto

  + Tata

    x Titi
```

The export to odt format should (I suppose) work in a similar fashion.

Comment: Step 1 works perfectly. Is there a way to have Step 2 working only within specific files (e.g. via adding an `#+OPTIONS` setting or something similar)?

Comment: I guess you can make this variable local at the end of the document; see for instance https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocalVariables

Comment: If I want numbering what should I do?